# SQL Query for Adding Up Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

[image]

My data is shown in the image. It should be filtered base on TDate as "As Of Date". If the desired month is May 2016, TotalCap is 39864.00. If month is June 2016, TotalCap should be 36, 192.58 and; if as of Date is July 2016, TotalCap should be 33898.44. How can we do that in MS SQL Server 2008? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 25 a.*, 
    (SELECT SUM(TotalCap) 
     FROM yourTable b 
     WHERE b.TDate <= a.TDate) AS RunningTotalCap
FROM yourTable a
```